# Kubernetes: run aws s3 sync/rsync against persistent volume on demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there a way in Kubernetes to trigger a job to run on my containers on demand?

The use case is to be able to have the containers sync from S3 to a persistent volume on demand.  In the application's current architecture, new content is added to S3 and is synced to a group of servers that are managed with Chef.  I need to have a way for a team to be able to trigger this functionality in the containers running on Kubernetes.

Comment: I don't know much about Kubernetes, but can you have cron in a container trigger a sync using the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Kubernetes represents a flexible mechanism for automated task workloads such as one time processes [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) and periodic processes like [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), which are included in `batch/v1` Kubernetes API object [model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#job-v1-batch), therefore solution from @Tim is quite decent for me.

I assume that it might be possible for you to spin up some pod with a `aws-cli` on a board in order to trigger sync action between mapped [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) into this container and target S3 storage. For that purpose you can build own image ported with necessary binary, or i.e. use ready solution like `docker-kubectl-awscli` image maintained by [@Expert360](https://github.com/expert360/docker-kubectl-awscli).

The following Job will execute `aws s3 sync` command inside particular container and launch sync action between target parties:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: backup-s3
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubectl-aws
        image: expert360/kubectl-awscli:v1.11.2
        env:
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: aws-s3-key
              key: aws-access-key-id
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: aws-s3-access-key
              key: aws-secret-access-key
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/ /data/backup" ]
        volumeMounts:
            - name: backup-aws
              mountPath: /data/backup
      volumes:
        - name: backup-aws
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: backup-aws-claim
      restartPolicy: Never
```

You have to supply `aws-cli` with corresponding `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables stored in particular Kubernetes [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) objects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the project : https://github.com/nuvo/skbn. It can also use kube2iam functionalities